# Error when I try to check version of Sudo on Linux Live Server via SSH

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, sudo, su

I'm getting this error

```
-bash: sudo: command not found
```

while trying to check version of Sudo using the following command

```
sudo -V
```

Here is the screenshot of it: [screenshotofbasherror--bash: sudo: command not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYQC7.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [this post contains screenshots of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/)...please remember that not everybody might have your eye foo. thanks for not posting screenshots of text.

Comment: `echo "$PATH"`? It may also be useful to know what specific kind of Linux the server is running.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

The reason may be that you don't have sudo package.

For me, the OS is CentOS-7.2 and I get the sudo command from the sudo rpm package.
This can be done from the following command:

```
yum provides /usr/bin/sudo
```

When you type the upper command, you can get the following output:

```
sudo-1.8.19p2-13.el7.x86_64 : Allows restricted root access for specified users
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/sudo



sudo-1.8.6p7-17.el7_2.x86_64 : Allows restricted root access for specified users
Repo        : @updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/sudo
```

And I can query the sudo rpm package

```
sudo-1.8.6p7-17.el7_2.x86_64
```